# How in Powershell see all XML Levels

Tags: powershell

I have a test xml and I want to get the value from this line ATTRIBUTE NAME="News- offers_OPT_EMAIL">F
so I can check for the value F or T

if I do below I can get the title but how do I get the above line value.

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content testFile.xml
$xml
$xml.CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER.NAME.TITLE
```

sample XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CUSTOMERS xml:lang="en">
    <CUSTOMER CREATED_DATE="2018-01-01 05:18:53.0" GROUP_ID="" ID="95656565">
        <NAME>
            <TITLE>M</TITLE>
            <FIRST_NAME>Joe</FIRST_NAME>
            <LAST_NAME>Smith</LAST_NAME>
        </NAME>
        <GENDER/>
        <DATE_OF_BIRTH/>
        <ADDRESS>
            <ADDRESS_LINE_1>1 White House</ADDRESS_LINE_1>
            <ADDRESS_LINE_2>Old Ave</ADDRESS_LINE_2>
            <ADDRESS_LINE_3/>
            <TOWNCITY>LONDON</TOWNCITY>
            <COUNTY/>
            <POSTCODE>18659</POSTCODE>
            <COUNTRY>France</COUNTRY>
        </ADDRESS>
        <ADDRESS>
            <ADDRESS_LINE_1>175 avenue de la division Leclerc</ADDRESS_LINE_1>
            <ADDRESS_LINE_2/>
            <ADDRESS_LINE_3/>
            <TOWNCITY>Antony</TOWNCITY>
            <COUNTY/>
            <POSTCODE>92160</POSTCODE>
            <COUNTRY>France</COUNTRY>
        </ADDRESS>
        <CONTACT_DETAILS>
            <TELEPHONE MARKETING_OPT_IN="F" TYPE="MOBILE">0123456789</TELEPHONE>
            <EMAIL MARKETING_OPT_IN="F">johnsmith@gmail.com</EMAIL>
        </CONTACT_DETAILS>
        <ATTRIBUTE NAME="News- offers_OPT_EMAIL">F</ATTRIBUTE>
        <NOTE>NA</NOTE>
    </CUSTOMER>
```

Comment: Also to add this is in Powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [SelectSingleNode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode?view=netcore-3.1) or [SelectNodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes?view=netcore-3.1) with an XPath expression. There are several options to achieve what you want, depending on your intention, but this would be one way to do it:

```bsh
# finde the nodes
$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='ATTRIBUTE'][@NAME='News- offers_OPT_EMAIL']")
# get value
$nodes.InnerText
```

Or if the value of the attribute doesn't matter, simply do:

```
$xml.customers.customer.attribute.'#text'
```

Comment: One last thing if I wanted to build an array of all the values would this do the trick  for above field $myArrayList.MYOFFERS = $xml.CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER.NAME['News- offers_OPT_EMAIL'].'#text'

Comment: @RogerClerkwell The first option I posted should return already an array of the values if there are more than one result in `$nodes`